# Cравнение дат без времени в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите где ошибся в сравнение с даты:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d"); 
UPDATE modx_shopkeeper3_orders SET gotov = 1 
WHERE status in (1,6,7) and 
      userid = 2 and 
      DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT(".$today.",'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Дата в базе вот в таком виде `2017-07-15 14:56:34`, мне нужно сравнивать без времени.

Comment: ...а что не так? и кто такой `mo.date` ?

Comment: ой, забыл убрать mo.
но все ровно без этого не работает, не обновляет поле

Comment: а все разобрался, DATE_FORMAT(".$today.",'%Y-%m-%d') нужно просто '".$today."''

Comment: вот только хотел об этом писать...

Comment: вообще и `DATE_FORMAT` не нужен...можно использовать **[DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp)**